# How to redirect to anchor in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is an anchor at the top of the page:

```
<a href="#top">Logo goes here</a>
```

At the bottom of the page, there is a contact form. I want to jump to the top of the page, to the anchor after completing the contact form.

```
$location.path("#top")
```

did not help.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do it the angular way. Use [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)
The example in the manual page is exactly what you want, except it scrolls to the bottom instead of the top...

Comment: It would be nice to give an example or else its not more that a link only answer

Answer (score 0):

$anchorScroll is the way to do it.  Here's an example of its use:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.gotoBottom = function(myTarget) { // this is the function to call with ng-click
      $location.hash(myTarget);  // set the target
      $anchorScroll();  // scroll to the target that has been set
    };
}]);
```

Then you would have HTML like the following:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <a ng-click="gotoBottom('goHere')">Scroll to my target location</a>
  <p>Some random stuff</p>
  <p>Some random stuff</p>
  <p>Some random stuff</p>
  <a id="goHere">This is where you scroll to</a>
</div>
```